# How to give user input to a java program , running as a free style project in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a Java file, `demo.java`, which asks for a user input and then simply displays it.
I just started with basics of Jenkins and wanted to run this java file (build this java file), but the build fails, but when I give any other `.java` file which does not requires user input, it works.

This is the `demo.java` file:

```
import java.util.*;

class demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
        String s = s.next();
        System.out.println("Hello "+s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run it in Jenkins? That is not what Jenkins is for.

Comment: `but the build fails` - how about sharing actual error(s), huh?

Comment: As already mentioned Jenkins purpose is not to execute Java application and provide input to them. If you want to test your application I would strongly advice to just write unit test and execute these as part of the pipeline. I also found [this article](https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2020/12/16/testing-standard-in-out-java/) that could be helpful. Also the variable s is defined twice you will need to rename one of the variables.